# What should the consistency of pudding be?

Tags: pudding, consistency

Like the title suggests, I'd like to know what should the consistency of a (chocolate) pudding be.

We don't actually have "pudding" where I am from, so I am having trouble deciding if I have made a pudding or just some sort of chocolate creme or if pudding is nothing else but a glorified random chocolate creme.

I know there are different types of pudding, but still any guideline would be appreciated.

If it helps I am using a mixture of:

- cocoa - 150ml
- sugar - 300ml
- cream -  50ml
- cornstarch - 130ml
- milk  - 820ml

I know I should measure some things by weight, but it's a long story. To clarify when measuring the cornstarch I shake the measuring cup until the starch is nice and compact, so it should be a lot.

What I get is a pudding that is thick, but if I angle the pot it still flows and tries to "escape". I am wondering if it shoul not be so thick that it would refuse to move even when the pot is angled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are making your pudding almost as thick as it should be.

It should be able to stand up a little. In other words, if you spoon some into a desert cup or small bowl, it should make a pile. It shouldn't be solid like ice cream, it should be smooth, but still stay in a pile shape.

Do you have custard where you live? It should be similar to that in thickness. Though custard is very different from
Chocolate pudding.

Comment: I'd add that it would seem that the pudding mentioned would be cooked. In general it will be thinner when hot than when cooled. I can't imagine a chocolate pudding served hot.

Comment: No, we do not have custard or anything relating to it or puddings. Well, except for Dr. Oetker's ready instant pudding mix or whatever. I was worried if increasing the amount of cornstarch would backfire, but now I will try it with even more as it seems to me I am almost to the point it will hold its own shape if I put it in a mold and invert.

Comment: @MaxW you know, I hadn't thought of it not being chilled yet. Haha

Answer (score 0):

It is always somewhat soft when it is in the pot. You have to let it set. After 12 hours or so, the usual pudding can hold its own shape. That is, it won't flow if you angle the bowl, and you can invert a mold of it and it will keep.

That being said, this is just a tradition. You can certainly make it wetter, like porridge or some polentas, and enjoy it that way.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to my pudding after it has set for more than a day in the fridge.  Inverting a mold is what I will compare it to, thanks!

Comment: I've had stuff that I'd consider a pudding that would still slump (ie, wouldn't maintain the shape of a mold after it's been released).  If you tilted a bowl of it, it wouldn't flow immediately, but if you let it sit for an hours or two, it would have moved.